# Snowflake ACCOUNT_USAGE.FUNCTIONS - No function type column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Under INFORMATION_SCHEMA there are two different views FUNCTIONS and PROCEDURES. But same is not there in ACCOUNT_USAGE.

SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.FUNCTIONS secured view documents both functions as well as procedures. But I don't see any column like function type to differentiate between functions and procedures.

How can we find which are functions and which are procedures from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.FUNCTIONS?

Thank you,
Srini

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing enhancement request for this exact requirement.